# Material Design - How to display an error on a larger screen

Tags: material-design, error-message

A bit similar to this question [Material Design - How to display a log in error](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/108995)

Though it doesn't address how to do this on a larger screen (i.e. desktop browser) since snackbar at the bottom as an error message is a bit weird on a larger screen, please see image below.

[image]

Official material design guidelines doesn't include any web-related guidelines for this case.

I'm currently using `angular 5` and `angular-material` which is designed to work both on desktop and mobile.

Answer (score 11):

The material design guidelines have a section called [Errors](https://material.io/archive/guidelines/patterns/errors.html#errors-app-errors).

For your use case, it recommends:

> If two or more fields have incompatible inputs:
>
> - In the text field, indicate a fix is needed. Add an error message below.
> - Display a message at the top of the form, or screen, summarizing the fixes needed and any additional explanation

This is what it looks like on mobile:

[image]

I imagine in your case, the bulk message could appear right below the "Sign in" heading.

As for snackbars, it goes on to say this:

> The snackbar contains app feedback about a peripheral error. Snackbars
> are transient. Don't use them for critical, persistent, or bulk
> errors.

Comment: This is exactly what I mentioned in my answer. Thanks for validating!

Comment: So I guess, it'll look somewhat like what any other front end framework will look like.

Comment: The link has been an archived one now:  https://material.io/archive/guidelines/patterns/errors.html#errors-app-errors  Does the new version of Material design not like it any more?

Comment: @JianChen From a cursory look, it seems there's no guidance on errors in the new HIG version at all, beside a very basic one for text fields. As the new version introduces a more flexible design system, perhaps the Errors page simply hasn't been upgraded yet? Either way, there are no recommendations that would advise against it, so the error patterns still seem valid to me.

Comment: Banners might fit this purpose, there's also a nice comparison between snackbar, banner and dialog: https://material.io/design/components/banners.html

Answer (score 3):

I would do away with the snackbar completely on the larger screen. I would do inline error messaging on larger screens right below the control in error along with highlighting the control in red as shown in your screenshot.

If you are married to the snackbar then below is my recommendation
1. Move the snack bar to the top on larger screens. Add animation so that the snackbar drops from the top of the screen.
2. Expand the snackbar to cover a larger area than shat you have currently. I would go about 3 times if not more as tall as you have it now

Material design specifications are said to be responsive but some of them do fall flat for larger screen renderings. But well nobody is perfect!

Let me know if that helps!

Comment: Married to the snackbar is the biggest form of commitment I have heard of